# Can not apply upsert when updating empty array item in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My db looks like:

```
[
  {
    id: 10,
    markets: []
  }
]
```

When I perform:

```
db.collection.update({
  id: 10
},
{
  $set: {
    "markets.$[element]": {
      eventId: 1,
      happy: 2
    },
  },
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      element: {
        eventId: 1,
      },
    },
  ],
  upsert: true,
})
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "id": 10,
    "markets": []
  }
]
```

However, when I changed the db to:

```
[
  {
    id: 10,
    markets: [
      {
        eventId: 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The update works. I wish to apply `upsert` here, so even if markets=[], I can still insert/add the object into db when `eventId` is not exist in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upsert works only on documents, not on single fields.

One solution is this one:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   { id: 10 },
   [
      {
         $set: {
            markets: {
               $concatArrays: [
                  { $filter: { input: "$markets", cond: { $ne: ["$$this.eventId", 1] } } },
                  [{
                     eventId: 1,
                     happy: 2
                  }]
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HNNGv7BU9Ik)

However, it will change the order of market elements.

Comment: thanks, it works. Can you explain a little bit about the answer, especially why using `$concatArrays` and `$$this`?

Comment: `$concatArrays` should be obvious, it combines two (more more) arrays into one. `$$this` is the default variable inside the filter, you could also write `{ $filter: { input: "$markets", as: "market", cond: { $ne: ["$$market.eventId", 1] } } }` - perhaps this makes it more clear.

Comment: so is the above code doing: first extract the item that its `eventId` is not equal to the target insertion's `eventId`, then concat with the insertion's `market`, and last, using `$set` to replace the corresponding `markets` field.

Comment: May I ask why after `{id: 10}`, `[]` is used instead of `{}`, I tried  `updateOne: {filter: { id: market.eventId },update: [{$set: {markets: {$concatArrays: [{$filter: {input: "$markets", cond: { $ne: ["$$this.eventId", market.eventId] },},}, [market], ],}, },},], }}. `With bulkWrite, however, I got `MongooseError: Invalid op passed to bulkWrite() Promise { { updateOne: { filter: [Object], update: [Array] } } }`

Comment: Check documentation [Update with an Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline)

Comment: I got an error after adding `filter` and `update` key in the bulk write, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can I know, without seeing any code from you? Please open a new question for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254311/discussion-between-tungtung-and-wernfried-domscheit).